# Fontsize (14) Apparently Not Working in a Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, tikz-pic

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\definecolor{boysenberry}{rgb}{.529, .196, .376}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\textbf{fontsize(15)}

\vskip 5pt
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=4pt,amplitude=2.5pt}
    } %
]
\node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.7,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
pencildraw,draw,fill=boysenberry,text width=\linewidth,inner sep=5mm]
{\fontsize{15}{10}\selectfont{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\lipsum[13]}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vskip 10pt

\textbf{fontsize(14)}

\vskip 5pt
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=4pt,amplitude=2.5pt}
    } %
]
\node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.7,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
pencildraw,draw,fill=boysenberry,text width=\linewidth,inner sep=5mm]
{\fontsize{14}{10}\selectfont{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\lipsum[13]}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\vskip 10pt

\textbf{fontsize(13)}

\vskip 5pt
\begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
    decorate,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=4pt,amplitude=2.5pt}
    } %
]
\node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.7,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},
pencildraw,draw,fill=boysenberry,text width=\linewidth,inner sep=5mm]
{\fontsize{13}{10}\selectfont{\textcolor{white}{\textbf{\lipsum[13]}}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

As one can see, there is no difference between the output of the size 15 font and the size 14 font. Furthermore, as size 16 (when I used it) produced a larger font, and as we can see, size 13 produces a smaller font, it appears that the *size 14* font is not being recognized for these tikzpictures, as well as for another one (not displayed here) that I have been using.

QUESTION: Can anyone tell me what the problem may be and how to correct it; i.e., have LaTeX recognize the 14 fontsize for these tikzpictures?

Thank you.

Comment: The fonts come with latex are in discrete sizes. The `\fontsize` command selects the nearest available size for you. You may also use `..., \large, \normalsize, \smaller, ...` to access all available sizes

Comment: @Symbol1 actually the fonts are scalable type1 fonts usable at all sizes, LaTeX just doesn't do that by default for computer modern fonts for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

14 is working, but 13 is not as latex clearly warns you:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/cmr/m/n' in size <13> not available
(Font)              size <12> substituted on input line 51.
```

You can add `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` to the start of the document to allow cm at all sizes, or use another font set, eg add `\usepackage{lmodern}`

Note that

```
\fontsize{13}{10}\selectfont
```

specifies 13pt font on a 10pt baseline which is never going to fit, so any linebreaking in the scope of such a command will produce inconsistent line spacing.

Note that this is completely unrelated to tikz, the example could be simplified to

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
zzz \fontsize{13}{10}\selectfont zzz

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the two remedies, as well as the helpful explanations as to the nature of the problem.

Comment: The system is making me wait to accept the answer.

Comment: @mlchristians I can survive for a few minutes without the points:-)

Comment: I am grateful for short, efficient answers. Thanks again for your help.